# InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Unknown identifier emp_id"

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh

I have created the keyspace and created the table inside it emp, its giving me error while inserting values, have I missed anything?

cqlsh> create keyspace dev WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy','replication_factor':1};
cqlsh> use dev
   ... ;
cqlsh:dev> create table emp(empid int primary key,emp_first varchar,emp_last varchar,emp_dept varchar);
cqlsh:dev> select * from emp

cqlsh:dev> insert into emp(emp_id,emp_first,emp_last,emp_dept) values(1,'fred','smith','eng');
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Unknown identifier emp_id"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your CREATE TABLE statement, you called it `empid`

In your INSERT statement, you called it `emp_id`.

Simply change `emp_id` in your INSERT statement to `empid`

```
INSERT INTO dev.emp (empid,emp_first,emp_last,emp_dept) values(1,'fred','smith','eng');
```